# Get a list of all Greek unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, python-module-unicodedata

I would like to know how to obtain a list of all Greek characters (upper and lowercase letters). I know how to find specific characters (`unicodedata.lookup(name)`), but I want *all* upper and lowercase letters.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What for? To print? Use in a regex? Have you checked if there are possibly lists of Unicode characters to find  online? (Which is the case: http://unicode.org claims to be complete.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Unicode standard](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf) defines the range `0x370` through `0x3ff` (inclusive) as Greek and Coptic symbols. The symbols that are exclusively Coptic (i.e. not shared with Greek) are `0x3e2` through `0x3ef` (inclusive).

You can thus iterate through the two ranges `0x370-0x3e1` (inclusive) and `0x3f0-0x3ff` (inclusive) to get all the Greek symbols, and use `str.isalpha()` to test each to see if it's a letter. For example:

```
from itertools import chain
greek_codes   = chain(range(0x370, 0x3e2), range(0x3f0, 0x400))
greek_symbols = (chr(c) for c in greek_codes)
greek_letters = [c for c in greek_symbols if c.isalpha()]
```